# Android - add my icon to the system area at the top (NOT notification)

Tags: android

Hi everyone!
I wonder how can I add my app icon to the system drawer that slides from the top of the screen, like Shazam does:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you should extend TileService to add your app to quick settings:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService